# Mover ventana sin bordes

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Buenas tardes comunidad.
Quisiera que alguien me ayudara con el siguiente código:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True)

w, h = 800, 500

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=w, height=h, highlightthickness=0)

canvas.pack(fill='both')

root.mainloop()
```

Lo que quiero es obtener una ventana sin bordes para que pueda colocar solo un borde superior personalizado con los botones de cerrar, minimizar y maximizar.

Tengo ese código pero no me deja mover la ventana solo la pone en un lugar estático, ni tampoco me aparece el icono de ejecución en la barra de tareas.

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que el método `overrideredirect` elimina al gestor de ventanas de la ecuación. Es decir, la ventana no será manejada por el gestor de ventanas del sistema operativo, no será decorada, no tendrá barra de título, icono en la barra de tareas, ni podrá ser cerrada, maximizada, minimizada o redimencionada por los métodos comunes provistos por él.

Para moverla, redimencinarla, cerrarla, minimizarla y maximizarla hay suficientes herramientas expuestas en Tkinter como para hacerlo (aunque no es trivial). Lo del icono en la barra de tareas es algo más complejo, se puede hacer algo como lo que se muestra [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30819099/7131499) del sitio en Inglés, pero el problema es que no es algo multiplataforma.

Otra opción menos "limpia" aunque más sencilla es crear una ventana con `TopLevel` que será nuestra ventana a la que aplicamos `overrideredirect` y luego mantenemos la ventana padre oculta en todo momento debajo de ella. Como la ventana padre si que está gestionada por el gestor de ventanas si tendremos el icono correspondiente en la barra de herramientas y sus funcionalidades (las cuales debemos extender a la ventana hija para que ambas actúen como una sola).

Un ejemplo es el siguiente:

```
import tkinter as tk



class BarraTitulo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, title=None, **kwargs):
        super(BarraTitulo, self).__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.title = title if title else tk.StringVar('')
        self.btn_close = tk.Button(self, text="X", command=self.close)
        self.btn_minimize = tk.Button(self, text="_", command=self.minimize)
        self.title_lb = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.title, fg="white", bg="black")
        self.btn_close.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.btn_minimize.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, pady=10)
        self.title_lb.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, padx=10, pady=10)

    def close(self):
        self.parent.destroy()
        self.parent.parent.destroy()

    def minimize(self):
        self.parent.withdraw()
        self.parent.parent.iconify()


class VentanaSinBordes(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kwargs):
        super(VentanaSinBordes, self).__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.overrideredirect(True)
        self.parent = parent
        self._x = 0
        self._y = 0

        self.borde = BarraTitulo(self, title=self.parent._title, background="black")
        self.contenido = tk.Frame(self)
        self.borde.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH)
        self.contenido.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH)
        self.borde.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.start_move)
        self.borde.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.stop_move)
        self.borde.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_move)
        self.borde.title_lb.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.start_move)
        self.borde.title_lb.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.stop_move)
        self.borde.title_lb.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_move)

    def start_move(self, event):
        self._x = event.x
        self._y = event.y

    def stop_move(self, event):
        self._x = None
        self._y = None

    def on_move(self, event):
        deltax = event.x - self._x
        deltay = event.y - self._y
        new_pos = "+{}+{}".format(self.winfo_x() + deltax, self.winfo_y() + deltay)
        self.geometry(new_pos)
        self.parent.geometry(new_pos)


class WindRoot(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(WindRoot, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.geometry('0x0')
        self._title = tk.StringVar(self.title())
        self.window = VentanaSinBordes(self)
        self.window.geometry('400x200')
        self.bind("<Map>", self.on_deiconify)
        self.bind("<Unmap>", self.on_iconify)


    def title(self, *args):
        if args:
            self._title.set(args[0])
        super(WindRoot, self).title(args)

    def on_iconify(self, event):
        self.window.withdraw()

    def on_deiconify(self, event):
        self.window.deiconify()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = WindRoot()
    root.title('Ventana sin bordes')
    root.mainloop()
```

El código es mejorable, pero muestra el procedimiento para poder mover la ventana al hacer click en una parte de ella, como crear botones para minimizarla o cerrarla, etc.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Disculpa la molestia, Que SO usas?

Comment: @LuisFernando en el caso concreto de la imagen se trata de [Manjaro](https://manjaro.org/) (rolling release basado en ArchLinux) con KDE Plasma 5 como entorno de escritorio (aunque está bastante personalizado).